# Erro code 0 in saving contacts phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to save a contact to contact list for an android device using phonegap(2.9.0),
Here is my code

```
function saveContactData() {
    var contact;
    contact = navigator.contacts.create();
    var tContactName = new ContactName();
    contact.displayName = $("#saveContName").val();
    tContactName.givenName = $("#saveContLName").val();
    contact.name = tContactName;

    var tPhoneNumbers = [];
    tPhoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('Office', $("#saveContOffNo").val(), true);
    tPhoneNumbers[1] = new ContactField('Mobile', $("#saveContMobNo").val(), false);
    contact.phoneNumbers = tPhoneNumbers;

    var temails = [];
    temails[0] = new ContactField('Office', $("#saveContEmail").val(), true);
    contact.emails = temails;

    var torgs = [];
    torgs[0] = new ContactOrganization();
    torgs[0].name = $("#saveContComp").val();
    contact.organizations = torgs;

//  console.log(JSON.stringify(contact));

    contact.save(addContsuccess, addContError);

    function addContsuccess(contSuccess){
        navigator.notification.alert('Saved sucessfully', function() {
                            }, 'Title');    
    }
    function addContError(contError) {
                    navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Error contact save: ' + contError.code, function() {
                    }, 'Title');
                }
}
```

I call this function onclick of certain button, All other configurations are set(Manifest). But Sometimes it throws me "Error code:0", even when contact is saved. Few blogs say(Click [here](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/09/saving-contacts-with-phonegap-android.html) !), its because no accounts are configured. But, In my emulator no accounts are configured it saves perfectly without any error most of the times. But in the device same code gives me Error:0 even when accounts are configured. Does anyone knows what Error code:0 refers to. can some one suggest me of what I am missing here? Thanks in adv :)

Answer (score 1):

Error code 0 means "unknown error". I am currently dealing with something similar. For some reason it is only doing this on my one Android device (a galaxy tab 3), but others I have tried it on (galaxy s3, galaxy s4) work perfectly with no error. The ios version gives no error. I did run accross an issue where ios was giving me a permissions error (error 20) but I resolved that on that particular iPhone by editing the restrictions.Wonder if something similar could be going on with Android?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to save more numbers to one contact. "More" in my case was 500. It turned out this number varies between Android versions.